# Remove nodes with date value older than today

Tags: c#, xml

In a C# application, if I have the following XML:

```
<SyncTable>
  <SyncEntry>
    <Cal_ID>1234</Cal_ID>
    <Cal_LastUpdated>2015-01-20T14:25:34.828-05:00</Cal_LastUpdated>
    <Cal_StartDateTime>2015-01-22T20:05:00-05:00</Cal_StartDateTime>
  </SyncEntry>
  <SyncEntry>
    <Cal_ID>4567</Cal_ID>
    <Cal_LastUpdated>2015-01-20T11:00:24.988-05:00</Cal_LastUpdated>
    <Cal_StartDateTime>2015-02-10T18:30:00-05:00</Cal_StartDateTime>
  </SyncEntry>
</SyncTable>
```

How can I search and delete the entries `<SyncTable>` where the `<Cal_StartDateTime>` entry is older than today?

Comment: Can you give an example of code that you've tried, or a specific issue that you are having with your solution?  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see what makes a question that is likely to get answered.

Comment: Did you try _anything_? How are you processing the XML in your C# program? Please show what you've accomplished so far, so that an answer can build on that properly.

Comment: Which Element are you trying to remove? The entire SyncTable element or just the Cal_StartDateTime element within? Or perhaps the SyncEntry element?

Comment: I am trying to remove the entire SyncTable element.  Being not overly familiar with XML I am asking what is the best way to do this.

Comment: I am thinking I could loop through all the nodes but is that most efficient way?  Is there away that can find all instances then delete each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing what you want:

```
string xml = @"
  <SyncTable>
    <SyncEntry>
      <Cal_ID>1234</Cal_ID>
      <Cal_LastUpdated>2015-01-20T14:25:34.828-05:00</Cal_LastUpdated>
      <Cal_StartDateTime>2015-01-22T20:05:00-05:00</Cal_StartDateTime>
    </SyncEntry>
    <SyncEntry>
      <Cal_ID>4567</Cal_ID>
      <Cal_LastUpdated>2015-01-20T11:00:24.988-05:00</Cal_LastUpdated>
      <Cal_StartDateTime>2015-02-10T18:30:00-05:00</Cal_StartDateTime>
    </SyncEntry>
  </SyncTable>
  ";

  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument() ;
  doc.LoadXml( xml ) ;

  DateTime       dtNow = DateTime.UtcNow ;
  DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal
                       | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal
                       | DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces
                       ;
  foreach( XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes( "/SyncTable/SyncEntry/Cal_StartDateTime" ) )
  {
    DateTime startDate ;
    bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact( node.InnerText , "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK" , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture , style , out startDate ) ;
    if ( !isValid || startDate < dtNow )
    {
      doc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(node.ParentNode);
    }
  }
```

At this point, `doc` has had all the offending `<SyncEnctry>` elements removed.

Answer (score 0):

A valid XML document must have a single root element. Your question & comments imply that you have multiple SyncTables, so I've added a root element to make this valid (`SyncTables`).

The code below will look through each `Cal_StartDateTime` value in a SyncTable and then use the maximum one found as the comparison against `DateTime.Now.Date`.

If you would prefer to use the minimum one, replace `Max` with `Min`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xmlString = @"<SyncTables>
<SyncTable>
  <SyncEntry>
    <Cal_ID>1234</Cal_ID>
    <Cal_LastUpdated>2015-01-20T14:25:34.828-05:00</Cal_LastUpdated>
    <Cal_StartDateTime>2015-01-22T20:05:00-05:00</Cal_StartDateTime>
  </SyncEntry>
  <SyncEntry>
    <Cal_ID>4567</Cal_ID>
    <Cal_LastUpdated>2015-01-10T11:00:24.988-05:00</Cal_LastUpdated>
    <Cal_StartDateTime>2015-02-10T18:30:00-05:00</Cal_StartDateTime>
  </SyncEntry>
</SyncTable>
</SyncTables>";

        var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);

        var syncTablesToRemove =
            xml.Elements("SyncTable")
                .Where(x =>
                    x.Descendants("Cal_StartDateTime")
                        .Select(y => DateTime.Parse(y.Value)).Max() < DateTime.Now.Date);

        foreach (var syncEntry in syncTablesToRemove)
        {
            syncEntry.Remove();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(xml);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Older than today", doesn't DateTime.Now include time? Also, wouldn't it be easier to use linq to select all records which are equal to or newer than today, rather than selecting the old ones and removing them in a loop?

Comment: I've adjusted to remove the SyncTable rather than the SyncEntry, as per the comment you added to your question.
Also added '.Date' to 'DateTime.Now', meaning it will only use the date part, i.e. 00:00 this morning.

Comment: If you want to use Linq to select records to keep then you'd need to construct a separate XML document in which to place them. Personally I think it's easier to select what needs to be removed and remove it from the original document. Linq XML classes (such as XElement) are a bit unusual in that operations such as 'Remove()' work on the original object. But you're welcome to try other ways if you want. :-)